# Problem with google play GAMES in my unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-games

I wanted to make achievements and ledarboard for my game, so I decided to use google play games, I did everything in the tutorial, changed the code a little and it works. When I have it loading in unity (made with unity), it displays my google play games profile at the top of the screen, but unfortunately the achievements and leaderboard don't add.
Code:
googleplayservices.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;

public class googleplayservices : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
    }

    internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            // Continue with Play Games Services
            // print(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId());
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(
            /* forceRefreshToken= */ false,
            code =>
            {
                Debug.Log(code);
                SignInWithGoogleAsync(code);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a login button
            // to ask users to sign-in. Clicking it should call
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ManuallyAuthenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
            Debug.Log("No");
        }
    }

    public void SignInWithGoogleAsync(string idToken)
    {
        // Your implementation goes here...
    }

    public void Osiagniecie(string id, int wartosc)
    {
        Social.ReportProgress(id, wartosc, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Score Update");
            }
        });
    }

    public void LeaderBoard(string id, int wartosc)
    {
        Social.ReportScore(wartosc, id, (bool success) =>
        {
            if (success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Score Update");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Nie udało się przesłać");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried placing the addition of achievements and to the leaderboard in different places. I did this until I finally went into Android Logcat and while it was supposed to post to the leaderboard I got an error:

```
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity Must authenticate first
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Local:VerifyUser()
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.Local:ReportScore(Int64, String, Action`1)
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity MoneyScript:AddMoney(Int32)
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity SceneManagerPlus:WinGo()
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
2023.06.07 12:22:21.015 6415 6450 Error Unity UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the user is authenticated before posting your score on the leaderboard.

```
if(PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IsAuthenticated())
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a second problem. He is not loading play games for me. In the sense that when I take upload to play store I don't see play games loading.